# What language is used in Tezos .arl files?

Tags: blockchain, tezos

So I read thru [this Rarible code](https://github.com/rarible/tezos-protocol-contracts) and they use the .arl files to write Tezos smart contracts. What language is `.arl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language used in these smart contracts is [Archetype](https://archetype-lang.org/)